# Slow performance of query with $and & $or operators

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, mongodb-3.6

My query with `$and`, `$or` operators is performing poorly. Even though I've built a compound index on all three fields that are specified in my query criteria, the query does a complete collection scan. I have tried both simple find and aggregation and the Winning plan for both is COLLSCAN.

#### Simple find

Query:

```json
db.test.find({ $or: [ {id1: "900004"}, {relatedid: "900004"}], $and: [ { isValid: "Y" } ] } )
```

Execution stats:

```json
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "XXX",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [ 
                {
                    "$or" : [ 
                        {
                            "Id1" : {
                                "$eq" : "900004"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "relatedID" : {
                                "$eq" : "900004"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "isValid" : {
                        "$eq" : "Y"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "Id1" : {
                                    "$eq" : "900004"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "relatedID" : {
                                    "$eq" : "900004"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "isValid" : {
                            "$eq" : "Y"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : []
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 61,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 100006,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [ 
                    {
                        "$or" : [ 
                            {
                                "Id1" : {
                                    "$eq" : "900004"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {
                                "relatedID" : {
                                    "$eq" : "900004"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    {
                        "isValid" : {
                            "$eq" : "Y"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 1,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 60,
            "works" : 100008,
            "advanced" : 1,
            "needTime" : 100006,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 781,
            "restoreState" : 781,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "direction" : "forward",
            "docsExamined" : 100006
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "XXXX",
        "port" : ,
        "version" : "4.0.9",
        "gitVersion" : "XXX"
    },
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

#### Aggregation

Query:

```json
db.test.aggregate( [{ "$match":{ "$and": [ {"isValid": "Y"}, { "$or": [ {"Id1": "900004"}, {"relatedID": "900004"} ]}] }} ] )
```

Execution Stats:

```json
{
    "stages" : [ 
        {
            "$cursor" : {
                "query" : {
                    "$and" : [ 
                        {
                            "isValid" : "Y"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "$or" : [ 
                                {
                                    "Id1" : "900004"
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "relatedID" : "900004"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "queryPlanner" : {
                    "plannerVersion" : 1,
                    "namespace" : "XXXXX",
                    "indexFilterSet" : false,
                    "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [ 
                            {
                                "$or" : [ 
                                    {
                                        "Id1" : {
                                            "$eq" : "900004"
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        "relatedID" : {
                                            "$eq" : "900004"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }, 
                            {
                                "isValid" : {
                                    "$eq" : "Y"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                        "filter" : {
                            "$and" : [ 
                                {
                                    "$or" : [ 
                                        {
                                            "Id" : {
                                                "$eq" : "900004"
                                            }
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            "relatedID" : {
                                                "$eq" : "900004"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }, 
                                {
                                    "isValid" : {
                                        "$eq" : "Y"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "direction" : "forward"
                    },
                    "rejectedPlans" : []
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1.0
}
```

How can I get a fast a query for my results?

Comment: This has been rectified and the query has been tuned. Below were the issues with the query

1. $or operator being used to search values in multiple fields
2. $and operator search value was on all the documents in the collection so in this case, it has to do complete collection scan

I built text index on all fields text fields in the collection:
db.ctmMappings.createIndex({"$**":"text"})

Then the below query worked just fine
db.test.find({ "$text": {"$search": "900004"}})

This query worked more efficiently than the previous ones

Comment: Update your comments in the answer and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has been rectified and the query has been tuned. Below were the issues with the query

1. $or operator being used to search values in multiple fields, which was not really efficient
2. $and operator search value was on all the documents in the collection so in this case, it has to do complete collection scan. Inefficient field chosen as index!

Fix applied:

I built text index on all fields text fields in the collection:

db.ctmMappings.createIndex({"$**":"text"})

Then reconstructed the query to below:

db.test.find({ "$text": {"$search": "900004"}})